# Android sharing google play install referrer url in social networks?

Tags: java, android, google-play, social-networking, referrals

I have to share the URL of my app in play-store with campaigner details in social networks and when the guest install the app i will use `com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER` for fetching the campaigner details.my doubt is how i will build the URL and share it programmatically.

Following is what i understand..

1) Create a URL which links play-store with our package name & unique referrer details like this `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hellochatty&referrer=tracking_id%3D123456789`

2)Share the URL via any social media

3)When click the shared link it will redirect to play-store and while installing the app we can get the `referrer` param using broadcast receiver.

```
 <receiver
     android:name="com.ex.MyReceiver"
     android:exported="true">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
     </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

Please let me know if anything wrong in my understandings ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything is correct. You can test your app configuration running this command in the terminal:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER 
                       -n your.package.name/path.to.receiver --es referrer
                       --es referrer "EXTRA_STRING_VALUE"
```

For example if your package name is `com.hellochatty` and the path of your receiver is `com.ex.MyReceiver` the test command will be:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER 
                       -n "com.hellochatty/com.ex.MyReceiver"
                       --es referrer "tracking_id=123456789"
```

Comment: Do you know how to do it on iOS?